# Trying to install Git on CentOS server

Tags: centos, git, installation

I'm trying to follow the steps mentioned here : http://wiki.railsmachine.com/InstallingGit

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install xmlto curl curl-devel
 # check for the latest version at http://git.or.cz/
wget http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.6.6.tar.gz
tar xvzf git-*.tar.gz
cd git-*
make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr --without-tcltk
make all
sudo make install
```

However, after typing `make all`, these are problems I get:

```
make: Warning: File `config.mak.autogen' has modification time 4e+02 s in the future
    SUBDIR perl
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/Config.pm', need       ed by `perl.mak'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Nevermind ... I just deleted the folder and re-created it. This time, it did give me a warning saying 'clock skew' detected, but it went through okay!

Answer (score 4):

If you've already got rpmforge added as a yum source, why not just install the git package from there?  It's a much newer version than the one you're compiling too.

Answer (score 0):

The git tarball contains a RPM spec file. I.e. you can create git binary RPMs right from the tarball with a single command: `rpmbuild -ta git-1.7.3.2.tar.gz`.

Now you can do a clean install from RPMs instead of writing directly to the filesystem with `make install`. (This has many advantages e.g. you can always query from which package a file comes from with `rpm -qf FILE` if everything is installed by RPM.)